# Can't install any R packages anymore

Tags: r, installation, clang, updates

I use [r](/questions/tagged/r) for biological data analysis. I'm on a `Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4`. I recently updated R to `version 3.6.3` because I thought that would solve my inability to install a particular package: `DESeq2`. Huge mistake - amongst the many I've probably made in trying to troubleshoot without really understanding what the problem is. I'm not able to install ANY packages now. I had updated my Clang version when I went down the rabbit hole of potential solutions on the internet. I was going to upgrade [gfortran](/questions/tagged/gfortran) too, but I want to understand what the problem is really before I blindly try more.

Now I've downgraded to `R 3.5.3` (I'd like to stick to this R version).

Qst: Using R 3.5.3, how do I successfully install packages from CRAN again? And also from Bioconductor like the DESeq2 package?

Error warning below:

```
install.packages("readr")
```

> ```
>     Warning in install.packages :
>       unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5:
>       cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'
>     Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of
>       C/C++/Fortran: ‘readr’
>     Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) y
>     installing the source package ‘readr’
>
>     trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/readr_1.3.1.tar.gz'
>
>     Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 268853 bytes (262 KB)
>     ==================================================
>     downloaded 262 KB
>
>     * installing *source* package ‘readr’ ...
>     ** package ‘readr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>     ** libs
>     clang++  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"
> -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include"
> -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -I. -Ircon -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c Collector.cpp -o Collector.o
>     clang++  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"
> -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include"
> -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -I. -Ircon -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c CollectorGuess.cpp -o CollectorGuess.o
>     clang++  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"
> -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include"
> -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -I. -Ircon -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c Iconv.cpp -o Iconv.o
>     clang++  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"
> -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include"
> -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -I. -Ircon -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c LocaleInfo.cpp -o LocaleInfo.o
>     clang++  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"
> -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include"
> -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -I. -Ircon -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
>     clang++  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"
> -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include"
> -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -I. -Ircon -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c Reader.cpp -o Reader.o
>     In file included from Reader.cpp:1:
>     In file included from ./Reader.h:3:
>     In file included from ./Collector.h:5:
>     In file included from ./DateTimeParser.h:6:
>     In file included from ./QiParsers.h:4:
>     In file included from ./boost.h:6:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/interprocess/file_mapping.hpp:15:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/config.hpp:57:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/config/platform/macos.hpp:28:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/config/detail/posix_features.hpp:18:
>     In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:655:
>     /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/gethostuuid.h:39:17:
> error: unknown type name 'uuid_t'
>     int gethostuuid(uuid_t, const struct timespec *) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_NA);
>                     ^
>     In file included from Reader.cpp:1:
>     In file included from ./Reader.h:3:
>     In file included from ./Collector.h:5:
>     In file included from ./DateTimeParser.h:6:
>     In file included from ./QiParsers.h:4:
>     In file included from ./boost.h:6:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/interprocess/file_mapping.hpp:15:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/config.hpp:57:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/config/platform/macos.hpp:28:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/config/detail/posix_features.hpp:18:
>     /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:662:27:
> error: unknown type name 'uuid_t'; did you mean 'uid_t'?
>     int      getsgroups_np(int *, uuid_t);
>                                   ^
>     /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_uid_t.h:31:31:
> note: 'uid_t' declared here
>     typedef __darwin_uid_t        uid_t;
>                                   ^
>     In file included from Reader.cpp:1:
>     In file included from ./Reader.h:3:
>     In file included from ./Collector.h:5:
>     In file included from ./DateTimeParser.h:6:
>     In file included from ./QiParsers.h:4:
>     In file included from ./boost.h:6:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/interprocess/file_mapping.hpp:15:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/config.hpp:57:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/config/platform/macos.hpp:28:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/config/detail/posix_features.hpp:18:
>     /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:664:27:
> error: unknown type name 'uuid_t'; did you mean 'uid_t'?
>     int      getwgroups_np(int *, uuid_t);
>                                   ^
>     /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_uid_t.h:31:31:
> note: 'uid_t' declared here
>     typedef __darwin_uid_t        uid_t;
>                                   ^
>     In file included from Reader.cpp:1:
>     In file included from ./Reader.h:3:
>     In file included from ./Collector.h:5:
>     In file included from ./DateTimeParser.h:6:
>     In file included from ./QiParsers.h:4:
>     In file included from ./boost.h:6:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/interprocess/file_mapping.hpp:15:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/config.hpp:57:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/config/platform/macos.hpp:28:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/config/detail/posix_features.hpp:18:
>     /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:727:31:
> error: unknown type name 'uuid_t'; did you mean 'uid_t'?
>     int      setsgroups_np(int, const uuid_t);
>                                       ^
>     /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_uid_t.h:31:31:
> note: 'uid_t' declared here
>     typedef __darwin_uid_t        uid_t;
>                                   ^
>     In file included from Reader.cpp:1:
>     In file included from ./Reader.h:3:
>     In file included from ./Collector.h:5:
>     In file included from ./DateTimeParser.h:6:
>     In file included from ./QiParsers.h:4:
>     In file included from ./boost.h:6:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/interprocess/file_mapping.hpp:15:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/config.hpp:57:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/config/platform/macos.hpp:28:
>     In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/config/detail/posix_features.hpp:18:
>     /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:729:31:
> error: unknown type name 'uuid_t'; did you mean 'uid_t'?
>     int      setwgroups_np(int, const uuid_t);
>                                       ^
>     /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_uid_t.h:31:31:
> note: 'uid_t' declared here
>     typedef __darwin_uid_t        uid_t;
>                                   ^
>     5 errors generated.
>     make: *** [Reader.o] Error 1
>     ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘readr’
>     * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/readr’
>     Warning in install.packages :
>       installation of package ‘readr’ had non-zero exit status
>
>     The downloaded source packages are in
>       ‘/private/var/folders/49/18qlr0bn7xg_mk2pzxvrb0f80000gn/T/RtmpN5hCja/downloaded_packages’
> ```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: The error says something about uuid_t and uid_t in C, it has nothing to do with gfortran.

Comment: How did you update R exactly? When  you update be sure to follow the guidelines for your platform.

Comment: The R development toolchain has changed overtime with respect to the compiler and gfortran requirements - I believe this is why the packages wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem on my Mac! I'm running Mojave. It appears there has been an issue with CRAN recently. Add the following repo argument has worked for me:

`install.packages("readr", repo = 'https://mac.R-project.org')`

More info: https://community.rstudio.com/t/i-can-t-install-packages-on-r-studio-non-zero-exit-status/52135

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the type uuid_t is not defined at anywhere. So the declaration at **line 662** in the file **/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h** will cause error for example.

In the first attempt, I tried to add one line into that unistd.h file:
**#include**  at **line 83**. But it doesn't help.

Because I don't want to go deeper to edit many system file, I add another line into unistd.h to manually define the type of uuid_t, based on the definition in _uuid_t.h.
**typedef __darwin_uuid_t uuid_t;** at **line 661**, after **"#endif"**.

Then it worked.

I am not sure if this is an error in the source code of MacOSX.10.15.sdk or not. But if you want to fix it in this way, please make sure you have the root permission when editing those files.

Answer (score 0):

I relied on these 2 posts to solve my issue:

https://www.nistara.net/post/compile-issues-r/

https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/

Thanks to the Coatless Professor and Nistara Randhawa